# How to create a list from filtering 2 lists with linq to object

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I wanted to know if there is a way using Linq to object to get a list from filtering 2 other lists. 
I have two lists of objects A and B, they are related two each other by an atribute(Code:String). B has another atribute, Name:String.

I want to get a list of A objects that meet 2 conditions.

-All of A objects must match their A.Code atribute to any of B.Code atribute in the B List.

-B.Name must be = "yoda";

I tried with this code(and another exampeles)
but it doesent seem to work and i dont know why.
I am just starting with linQ.

```
List<A> FilteredAList = (from OneA in ListOfA
                         join  OneB in ListOfB
                         on OneA.Code equals OneB.Code
                         where OneB.Name == "yoda"
                         select  OneA).ToList<A>();
```

Thanks in Advance!.

Comment: Tested it  just now, and I get 0 results, even though the list of B has several yodas , and the list of b has serveral codes that matches the A codes.

Comment: Are you talking about my code posted in my answer? If so, I'm sure the elements in `ListOfB` having `.Name="yoda"` don't have `Code` matching any in `ListOfA`. The both conditions should be considered. You could post the sample data of `ListOfB` and `ListOfA` so that I can test.

Answer (score 5):

With your requirement, I think we should use `Any` method, therefore we should write `method query` not `expression query`. Of course I don't know the equivalent of `Any` in `expression query` (At least it should be **short** as in the `method query`, otherwise, it's not good). If any one knows, please leave some comment. Thanks for that.

```
var FilteredAList = ListOfA.Where(x=>ListOfB.Any(y=>x.Code==y.Code && y.Name=="yoda"))
                           .ToList<A>();
```